# How to compare two files using if loop?

Tags: shell

I have a file named file1.txt that looks like this:

```
Alex Dog
Ana  Cat
Jack Fish
Kyle Mouse
```

And a file named file2.txt that looks like this:

```
Alex Lion
Ana  Cat
Jack Fish
Kyle Mouse
```

What would be a good way to run a loop that checks if the names (Alex, Ana etc) still own the same pets (second column)?
I want the script to run the compare and then if they all match do nothing. If there is 1 mismatch or more Echo the pet that has been changed. For example on these two files (file1.txt and file2.txt) the script would print:

```
Lion
```

Comment: Simple answer, you could `diff` the files.

Comment: That is not my goal though. My goal is to print the word that is causing the diff from the second file as shown in my example.

Comment: `join` the files on first column, printing only second columns. Then `awk` compare the columns, and if they don't match output. `the script would print:` Why wouldn't it print `Dog`? Is file2 more important then file1?

Comment: Can you provide an explanation on how the compare + echo diff is done? Yes file 2 is the more important data I need.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of assumptions in the following code, but it works as per KamilCuk's design:

```
$ join  file1.txt file2.txt | awk ' $2 != $3 { print $3} '
Lion
```

Assumptions:

1. files are sorted
2. the files have the same people in the same order
3. the people have only first names - no spaces in the names

If we want to do a little better, we can sort the inputs and allow the names to have spaces as follows:

```
$ join  <( sort file1.txt)  <( sort file2.txt ) | awk ' $(NF - 1)  != $NF { print $NF } '
```

Comment: Assumption 3 is valid in all cases. Not sure what you mean by "sorted". Is there a way to eliminate assumption 2?

Comment: By sorted I mean that the names appear in alphabetical order:  Alex, Ana, Jack, and Kyle is sorted.  The join utility requires both files to be sorted.  While it's unnecessary with your input, I show you how you can sort both files prior to inputting them to join.  Regarding assumption 2 - this is saying that the files are sorted again.  But it also says, that you need the same people.  If there is a person in file1but not in file2, join will miss it.  join (without -v1 or -v2 option) will only report on lines that match.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all lines in `file2.txt` that are found in `file1.txt` and show after the space.

```
grep -vf file1.txt file2.txt | cut -d" " -f2
```

Edit:
You asked for a loop. A loop will use a lot more resources and should be avoided (use `awk` when you can not think of smart commands, perhaps with some pipes).

```
# Avoid the following slow loop
while read -r name animal; do
   grep "^${name} " file2.txt | grep -v " ${animal}$" | cut -d" " -f2
done < file1.txt
```

Comment: Thanks ! this was helpful!